# MVP ErrorControl Property

Tags: c#, properties, pass-by-reference, mvp, errorprovider

I'm using an MVP pattern to expose field values from my View to my Presenter. I'd like to add an `ErrorProvider` to my View and add the errors from the Presenter, but that would mean exposing my controls, which I'm not keen on doing. My solution involved creating an `ExposableControlValue` class that exposes a value generically and has the added function `CreateError(string errorMessage)`.

```
public interface IExposableControlValue<T>
{

  T Value { get; set; }

  void CreateError(string errorMessage);

  void ClearErrors();

}
```

My thought was, I'll pass in the `Property` by reference and now my generic value will essentially point to the `Control`'s backing field. All the `ErrorProvider` logic could be handled View side and all of the error checking could be handled by the presenter.

Obviously, I'm here because you can't pass the `Property` by reference, and all of the examples I've seen aren't close enough to my situation that I can decipher them for this example.

I'd also be fine with setting `T Get()` , `Set(T value)`methods dynamically if there is a way to do that, but in short, I'd like to mimic having that Property 'live' inside of my class instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question as I finally was able to work this to my desired needs.

Using a factory pattern, I was able to make a new method `CreateNew`

```
  public IExposableControlValue<T> CreateNew<T>(ErrorProvider errorProvider, Control control, Func<T> get, Action<T> set) {
     var param1 = new ConstructorArgument("errorControl", errorProvider);
     var param2 = new ConstructorArgument("control", control);
     var exposableControlValue = resolutionRoot.Get<IExposableControlValue<T>>(param1, param2);
     exposableControlValue.CreateSet(set);
     exposableControlValue.CreateGet(get);

     return exposableControlValue;
  }
```

I'm using `ninject`, but the concept is the same. Essentially I'm asking the user for a few dependcies to create a new instance of this class. Then, when I want to actually expose the inner Generic value, I do it like so:

```
  Func<T> get;

  Action<T> set;

  public ExposableControlValue(ErrorProvider errorControl, Control control) {
     ...configure my dependcies
  }

  public T Value { get { return get.Invoke(); } set { set.Invoke(value); } }
```

Finally, when I actually use the factory `CreateNew` method, I pass in some arguments depending on the property that I need

```
 _forSomethingBackingField = exposableControlFactory.CreateNew<decimal>(errorProvider, numericUpDownForSomething, 
        () => { return numericUpDownForSomething.Value; }, (decimal d) => { numericUpDownForSomething.Value = d; });
```

The `decimal` is my generic value for the `numeric up down`. If you wanted to do this with a `string`, you would simply use `string` as the generic argument and pass `(string s) = > someControlWithTextProperty.Text = s` to the anonymous method param. Of course, doing so you would want to make sure that the Property that you are using is actually of the type you pass.